# How to debug the issue for Airflow DAG disappearing automatically from Webserver UI

Tags: airflow

Airflow DAG disappearing automatically from Webserver UI

We have multiple DAGs running at Airflow-2.3.2. One of particular DAG disappears automatically from the Webserver UI on random day (observed this issue couple of times). This DAG is having schedule_interval as None and runs on demand triggers externally. There is no change in DAG right before it disappears from the UI. DAG starts listing again immediately after a Webserver service restarts without any changes.

Tried following things -

- Webserver logs has no error captured.
- airflow dags list command is not showing this DAG

Any idea or steps to further debug or troubleshoot the issue would be very helpful.

Thanks!!

Comment: can you check the dag parser logs and scheduler log?

Comment: Did you find the root cause and/or the solution?